# IsLoaded property for a UserControl in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

It looks as if there is no `IsLoaded` property in a `UserControl` object in XAML, even if the `Loaded` event is there.

But the [MSDN page on IsLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isloaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tells that it should be there since `UserControl` derives from `FrameworkElement`.

So I guess it was removed in XAML (the doc is for WPF). But I can't believe they just deleted it in WinRT, they must have replaced it with something else?

**So, question**:
How do I gain access to the `IsLoaded` boolean of a `UserControl` in WinRT?

Of course, it is always possible to do it by hand on every user control by registering a callback on the `Loaded` event, but it is a pain for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `FrameworkElement.IsLoaded` in Silverlight either, and WinRT is much closer to Silverlight than it is to WPF.

As to why it was removed, I can make an educated guess based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isloaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the WPF property:

> From a newly constructed FrameworkElement, this property starts off
>   false, and remains true after it is set to true, even if the element
>   is subsequently removed from a connected logical tree by code. true
>   state is set by the general presentation logic when elements are
>   loaded into the presentation engine.

Basically, the property in WPF is sometimes *wrong*. A control can load (and fire its `Loaded` event) multiple times, and be unloaded in the meantime. The WPF `IsLoaded` property can says a control is loaded even when it's not really. That's... very bad.

They probably removed it rather than fixing it because of at least one of these reasons:

- They didn't want to break compatibility within WPF to older versions, or have a property which acts differently in WPF vs SL / WinRT
- Tracking whether something is loaded or not is difficult and easy to get wrong, and so is inherently dangerous
- Querying the loaded state of a control might be bad practice / a bad idea anyway

If you really do want to implement it yourself, then at least listen to `Unloaded` as well as `Loaded`. But I think that depending on what you're trying to do, there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

A "Loaded" control is simply one that is in the visual tree, so you could check if there is a path between your control and the RootVisual of the application using VisualTreeHelper, but it might not be very efficient and I would still recommend handling the event. You could implement an attached property/behavior that would give you a bindable IsLoaded property if you really need it often.

Comment: Ok, looks like I'm going to stick to setting `IsLoaded` myself, but it's a pain, and it doesn't make sense to me. Anyway, not too serious :) Btw, it also guarantees that all its children are also in the visual tree, right?

Comment: As soon as the loaded event has been fired, it would be correct to assume the visual tree has been parsed and loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `IsLoaded` property in the Windows Runtime version of the framework. As you point out, the link you provide is not for the Windows Runtime. For that, see this MSDN link: [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#properties).

The `Loaded` event seems to be the only way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Do you know the rationale behind that? I can't see a good reason for just deleting this property.

Comment: @Mic - no, sorry I don't know why.